# ValueError: signal only works in main thread when using Stomp

Tags: python, web-scraping, stomp

When I run this code I get this error:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

I'm using ActiveMQ.

RealTor is the name where i have my Spider(selogerSpider) this one help me for the scraping.

```py
import stomp
from RealTor import selogerSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.settings import Settings


class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
def on_error(self, headers, message):
    print('received an error "%s"' % message)
def on_message(self, headers, message):
    print('received a message "%s"' % message)

    settings = Settings()
    settings.set("USER_AGENT",
                 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) 
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36")
    settings.set("LOG_ENABLED", False)
    crawler = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    crawler.crawl(selogerSpider)
    selogerSpider.signals.engine_started()
    print("STARTING scraping")
    crawler.start()
    print("Scraping STOPPED")
try:
conn = stomp.Connection()
conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
conn.start()
""" conn = stomp.Connection([('0.0.0.0', 61613)])"""
conn.connect('admin', 'password', wait=True)
conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/test', id=1, ack='auto')
print('subscripe')
"""conn.send(body=' '.join(sys.argv[1:]), destination='/queue/test')"""
input("coucou")
"""conn.disconnect()"""
print('end')

except IOError as e:
  print("error message")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem doesn't have anything to do with ActiveMQ. You're misusing signals. As the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) states:

> Python signal handlers are always executed in the main Python thread, even if the signal was received in another thread. This means that signals can’t be used as a means of inter-thread communication. You can use the synchronization primitives from the threading module instead.
>
> Besides, only the main thread is allowed to set a new signal handler.

I believe the `on_message` method is executed in its own thread since the message is received asynchronously.

In short, *don't* use signals from threads. Use the synchronization primitives from the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) instead. If you can't avoid using signals then receive the STOMP message synchronously on the main thread instead of using a `ConnectionListener`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it in python3.7.3 by by applying this patch manually to `/usr/lib/python3.7/pdb.py`

```
https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8d64bfafdffd9f866bb6ac2e5b4c4bdfcb16aea0
```

I suppose that there are better ways to achieve the same (say, pass a patched file as a parameter)  without patching python library, but this one seems good enough.

It will be really nice if this patch will be back ported to popular releases.

Answer (score 1):

The problem fixed after I installed:

```
pip3 install "pyzmq==17.0.0" "ipykernel==4.8.2"
```