# MITMProxy with GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5, mitmproxy

Is it possible to run mitmproxy with pyqt5 GUI app?
It just freezes my app

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from multiprocessing import Process

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My Window")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200)

def start_mitmdump():
    from mitmproxy.tools.main import mitmdump
    mitmdump(['-q', '-s', __file__, '--ssl-insecure'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start mitmdump in a separate process
    mitm_process = Process(target=start_mitmdump)
    mitm_process.start()

    # Start PyGUI application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()

    # Wait for the mitmdump process to finish
    mitm_process.join()

    # Exit the application
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried doing this but it returns an error

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from threading import Thread

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My Window")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200)

def start_mitmdump():
    from mitmproxy.tools.main import mitmdump
    mitmdump(['-q', '-s', __file__, '--ssl-insecure'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start mitmdump in a separate thread
    mitm_thread = Thread(target=start_mitmdump)
    mitm_thread.daemon = True  
    mitm_thread.start()

    # Start PyGUI application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()

    # Start the Qt event loop
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 982, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "D:\python new\ProxyGUI\mitm_mre.py", line 13, in start_mitmdump
> mitmdump(['-q', '-s', **file**, '--ssl-insecure'])   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mitmproxy\tools\main.py",
> line 150, in mitmdump
> run(dump.DumpMaster, cmdline.mitmdump, args, extra)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mitmproxy\tools\main.py",
> line 127, in run
> return asyncio.run(main())
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
> return runner.run(main)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
> return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 654, in
> run_until_complete
> return future.result()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mitmproxy\tools\main.py",
> line 121, in main
> signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, _sigint)   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\signal.py", line 58, in signal
> handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the code you've provided that should be mucking about with signals; what does the *full* stack trace look like for the error in question? Why does [this canonical for the error message in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54749342/valueerror-signal-only-works-in-main-thread-when-using-stomp) not address your issue? Can you make sure your code is conformant to the guidance on creating a [mre]? See [ask]

Comment: Maybe try embedding https://mitmproxy.org/#mitmweb to a QT browser ?

Comment: @esqew The error is reproducible with this mre. I have updated full error message. 


I'm guessing mitmproxy needs to be run inside main thread but running it in main thread freezes up gui loop. The only solution I can think of at the moment is to try webapp for gui

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.